# AME doesn't export the right opacity

Tags: after-effects, adobe-media-encoder

My picture layer background color was set to white, so in AE it appeared to be light. But in AME it used a black background color instead, so it appeared to be dark. I fixed this by adding a white solid layer under all other layers.

It's so confusing for a newbie like me.

In my AE it appears like this
[image]

but in AME it renders this
[image]

if I choose Render Alpha Channel Only, it appears like this
[image]

I'm wondering how to make the rendered one look like the one in AE

Answer (score 0):

Media Encoder is notoriously unreliable for correctly rendering anything out of Premiere or After Effects. I would only use it for very simple comps and sequences.  Anything else seems to confuse it.

If you need to automate a lot of renders, you could try rendering them from the command line instead?

https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/automated-rendering-network-rendering.html

Comment: I tried using render but without the encoder my video turned out to be hundreds of GB, which made my disk full.